# What is XmlHttpRequestError INTERNAL SERVER ERROR?

Tags: json, python-2.7, date, onchange, typeerror

I made a method for an `on_change` method and here is my code:

```
def onchange_date_start(self, cr, uid, ids, date_start, context=None):
    factor = 2
    date_1 = datetime.strptime(date_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
    date2 = date_1.date()
    end_date = datetime(date2.year,date2.month,date2.day) + relativedelta(months=+factor)
    e_date = end_date
    _logger.info("\n\t\t\t\tEND Date Final %s"%(str(e_date.date())))
    value = {"value":{"end_on" : e_date.date()}}
    return value
```

So far it prints out my `e_date` correctly but an error also pops up saying:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

and here is what the terminal says:

```
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.date(2015, 10, 18) is not JSON serializable
```

What error did I make?

**Thanks for any help/suggestion**

Comment: The date object isn't serializable, so try converting it to a string first.

Comment: something like this: str(date_start) ?